# How to realm database retrieve a nameKey-value in react-native?

Tags: database, react-native, realm

I needs a database for a react-native Android / iOS app.  As a first step in learning realm, I want to replace AsyncStorage with realm to read application settings.

1. Question: What is syntax to access value by nameKey?

My AppSetting schema sets name as primary key:

```
const AppSetting = {
  name: 'AppSetting',
  primaryKey: 'name',
  schemaVersion: 1,
  properties: {
    name:   {type: 'string'},
    value:   {type: 'string'},
  }
};
```

If appSettings is empty, then I write AppSettingsDefault:

```
const AppSettingsDefault = [
  {
    name: 'version',
    value: '0,'
  },
  {
    name: 'gpsEnabled',
    value: 'true,'
  },
  {
    name: 'unitType',
    value: '2,'
  },
];
console.log('appSettings.length:', appSettings.length);
if(0 >= appSettings.length) {
  console.log("Init default: AppSetting when app is run first time");
  for(let i = 0; i < AppSettingsDefault.length; ++i) {
    let name = AppSettingsDefault[i].name;
    let value = AppSettingsDefault[i].value;
    console.log(name, '=', value);
    realm.write(()=>{
      realm.create('AppSetting', {
        name: name,
        value: value,
      });
    })
  }
}
```

What is realm syntax to retrieve value of 'gpsEnabled' in react-native ?

```
let realm = new Realm({schema:
  [AppSetting], schemaVersion: 1});
let appSettings = realm.objects('AppSetting');
// How to retrieve a value by the primary key?
console.log('gpsEnabled', appSettings['gpsEnabled'];  <- This does NOT work
```

Thanks in advance for any tips or direction,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 let result = realm.objects('AppSetting').filtered('name = "gpsEnabled"');
 let val = result[0].value;
```

https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#queries

Comment: Thank you! Realm for Swift has a objectForPrimaryKey(_:key:) method. If objectForPrimaryKey also exists for react-native, what does the javascript syntax look like? Sorry, realm, react-native, javascript newbie.

Comment: As far I can see at https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/src/js_realm.cpp ,it doesnt seem to support objectForPrimaryKey yet.  You could probably raise an issue there.